# Intercept incoming flash messages on android mobile

Tags: android, sms, intercept, flash-message

can anyone help me to intercept the incoming Flash messages (specially the ones from the telecom company, where they send our current balance after some activity like message sent).

My application deals with sending SMSes in bulk and I don't want the flash message popping now and then. So is it possible on Android ?

EDIT: Everyone says its not possible above Android 1.6 but I found a [similar App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.melkote.quietbalance&hl=en) on Google Play but I want the source of that kind of App. Please Help.

Edit: More than a year has passed and still I didnt got the solution. Can anyone help to resolve this thread..??

Comment: did you find a solution/work around?

Comment: @Johnx-No man..I just dropped the idea. But please post here if u succeed in this!

Answer (score 2):

Might depend on the channel [of communication] used by your service provider. I guess they don't use SMS, probably they use WAP/PUSH or some pre-installed provider app for the notifications, which makes this harder to block. If it was SMS, you'd definitely have lots of ways to block their notifications, but in this case, I doubt there might be an easy / direct way to do this.

*Flight Mode* should ideally block telco / service-provider messages / notifications, but then this also blocks your connectivity, right? So, am not so certain on this one. Isn't there a way to opt-out of service provider notifications, maybe via a ussd routine? I've heard of this once...

Comment: @nemesisfix-No..there isnt any way to block it via ussd routine..i already tried that one !! But thanks for replying..

Answer (score 2):

Flash sms it is the same as usual sms except data coding flags. It has "class 0" indication in DCS.

For details about sms coding see: [GSM 3.38 specification](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/0338.htm) / 4 SMS Data Coding Scheme.

Some fragment from spec about it

> When a mobile terminated message is class 0 and the MS has the capability of displaying short messages, the MS shall display the message immediately and send an acknowledgement to the SC when the message has successfully reached the MS irrespective of whether there is memory available in the SIM or ME. The message shall not be automatically stored in the SIM or ME.

So, in most cases, phone just displays this message and skips usual chain of actions.
Probably, you can't catch this message with usual API... probably you need deep hook and rooted device.

[Or may be just switch off this service by calling customer support?]